# How to Create a user in Security.Users using Cache Class?

Tags: intersystems-cache, intersystems

I am new to Intersystems Cache. I am trying to create a user via cache class i.e., through.cls file.

Is it possible?
***Note***: From documentation I found that **create**(username,.....) API available.

Please suggest some fruitful solutions.

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.intersystems.com/ens20102/csp/documatic/%25CSP.Documatic.cls?PAGE=CLASS&LIBRARY=%25SYS&CLASSNAME=Security.Users

Please check the above link...

Comment: thanks, I saw the above documentation before itself, please suggest some snippets.